# Getting errors I don't think I should be in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm learning C, and I'm making a program that converts between SI Units and English units. I'm getting these errors:

```
73:21: warning: format specifies type
      'float *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%f", choicemtfftm);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~

100:21: warning: format specifies type
      'float *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%f", choiceytmmty);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~

121:5: error: expected expression
    else if (choice==5)
    ^

2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

But I shouldn't be, I don't think, especially because I have several other variables in the program that do the same thing as choicemtfftm and choiceytmmty. I also don't understand why 
I am getting an error on else if, because I have 3 other of those statements that aren't complaining. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    float Lb,Kg,Mi,Km,Meters,Feet,Yards,Gallons,Liters,choice,choicemtkktm,choiceptkktp,choicegtlltg,choiceytmmty,choicemtfftm;

    printf("What do you want to convert (1-5)?\n1. Miles to Kilometers\n2. Pounds to Kilograms\n3. Meters to Feet\n4. Yards to Meters\n5. Gallons to Liters\n");
    scanf("%f",&choice);

    if(choice==1)
    {
        printf("Would you like to convert miles to kilometers (enter 1) or kilometers to miles (enter 2)");
        scanf("%f",&choicemtkktm);
        if (choicemtkktm==1)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in miles\n");
            scanf("%f",&Mi);
            Km = (Mi*1.6);
            printf("Distance of %f miles is %f kilometers.\n\n",Mi,Km);
        }
        else if (choicemtkktm==2)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in kilometers\n");
            scanf("%f",&Km);
            Mi = (Km/1.6);
            printf("Distance of %f kilometers is %f miles.\n\n",Km,Mi);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    else if (choice==2)
    {
        printf("Would you like to convert from pounds to kilograms (enter 1) or kilograms to pounds (enter 2)?");
        scanf("%f",&choiceptkktp);
        if (choiceptkktp==1)
        {
            printf("Enter weight in pounds\n");
            scanf("%f",&Lb);
            Kg = (Lb/2.2);
            printf("Weight of %f pounds is %f kilograms.\n\n",Lb,Kg);
        }
        else if (choiceptkktp==2)
        {
            printf("Enter weight in kilograms\n");
            scanf("%f",&Kg);
            Lb = (Kg*2.2);
            printf("Weight of %f kilograms is %f pounds.\n\n",Kg,Lb);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    else if (choice==3)
    {
        printf("Would you like to convert from meters to feet (enter 1) or meters to feet (enter 2)?");
        scanf("%f", choicemtfftm);
        if (choicemtfftm==1)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in meters\n");
            scanf("%f",&Meters);
            Feet = (Meters*3.28);
            printf("Distance of %f meters is %f feet\n\n",Meters,Feet);
        }
        else if (choicemtfftm==2)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in feet\n");
            scanf("%f",&Feet);
            Meters = (Feet/3.28);
            printf("Distance of %f feet is %f meters\n\n",Feet,Meters);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }


    else if (choice==4)
    {
        printf("Would you like to convert from yards to meters (enter 1) or from meters to yards (enter 2)?");
        scanf("%f", choiceytmmty);
        if (choiceytmmty==1)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in yards\n");
            scanf("%f",&Yards);
            Meters = (Yards*0.9144);
            printf("Distance of %f yards is %f meters\n\n",Yards,Meters);
        }
        else if (choiceytmmty==2)
        {
            printf("Enter distance in meters\n");
            scanf("%f",&Meters);
            Yards = (Meters/0.9144);
            printf("Distance of %f meters is %f yards\n\n",Meters,Yards);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    else if (choice==5)
    {
        printf("Would you like to convert from gallons to liters (enter 1) or from liters to gallons (enter 2)?");
        scanf("%f",choicegtlltg);
        if (choicegtlltg==1)
        {
            printf("Enter volume in gallons\n");
            scanf("%f",&Gallons);
            Liters = (Gallons*3.78541);
            printf("Volume of %f gallons is %f liters\n\n",Gallons,Liters);
        }
        else if (choicegtlltg==2)
        {
            printf("Enter volume in Liters\n");
            scanf("%f",&Liters);
            Gallons = (Liters/3.78541);
            printf("Volume of %f liters is %f gallons\n\n",Liters,Gallons);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input. Program has ended.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you get the error for the `else if` because you forgot the closing `}` for the preceeding block...

Comment: Of course it should show error, check how many `}` you have. Next time avoid saying things such as *"it shouldn't be showing an error"* and look closer.

Answer (score 3):

For the warnings, you forgot to put `&` before the variable name in `scanf("%f", choicemtfftm);`, and likewise for the other one.

For the error, you forgot to close the `if (choice==4) {...` block with a `}`.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much. I'm not sure why I'm getting negative votes though.